# How to insert multiple postmeta values with one query?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, post-meta, wpdb

I have a custom script/plugin I am using for myself that creates a post along with some postmeta information. Right now, I have multiple `$wpdb->insert`, but I would like to condense this down into one query. How would I do this?

Here is my current code:

```
$meta_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';

    $wpdb->insert( 
    $meta_table, 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, // Already defined
        'meta_key' => 'client-pwd',
        'meta_value' => $post_pwd // Already defined
        )
        );  

$wpdb->insert( 
    $meta_table, 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'meta_key' => 'gallery-status',
        'meta_value' => 'private'
        )
        );  

$wpdb->insert( 
    $meta_table, 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'meta_key' => 'meta-description',
        'meta_value' => 'Description...'
        )
        );  

$wpdb->insert( 
    $meta_table, 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'meta_key' => 'can-purchase',
        'meta_value' => 'yes'
        )
        );  

$wpdb->insert( 
    $meta_table, 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'meta_key' => 'can-email',
        'meta_value' => 'yes'
        )
        );  

$wpdb->insert( 
    $meta_table, 
    array( 
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'meta_key' => 'can-download',
        'meta_value' => 'yes'
        )
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert multiple rows via wpdb's `insert`, you have to do it with raw SQL:

```
INSERT into $meta_table (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES
('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
('otherval1', 'otherval2', 'otherval3')
```

**However-**

You should always use the API where a function exists- use [`add_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) so your plugin integrates with the WordPress environment and its behavior can be modified without having to edit the plugin's files directly.